# Gurobi Callback After Optimal Solution

Tags: java, callback, gurobi

I am trying to get Gurobi to call back after an optimal solution is found (using the Java interface).

Background: I am working on an approach which requires (1) finding a (very) good solution and then (2) adding a lazy constraint to the problem. A good solution has to be found first since identifying a reasonable new lazy constraint requires a good solution in my case.

In general, this is not a problem since Gurobi calls back with MIP, MIPSOL etc.; I can then check the gap of the current solution and decide on adding the next lazy constraint.

However, when looking for a very good solution, Gurobi sometimes finds an optimal solution (for instance after cutting nodes off). In this case, there is no additional MIP, MIPSOL or any other usable callback which would me allow to add an additional lazy constraint.

I have already found that cutoffs can be identified using MIPNODE_STATUS. I have however not yet found a way to check if this cutoff leads to the currently solution being proven optimal.

Does anybody know to identify this case and still add a lazy constraint?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to check if the model is optimal and the lazy constraint not added after the `optimize()`-method is finished. In such a case, just add the lazy constraint and call `optimize()` again.

In this case, the second optimization starts with the solution of the first one. I am not sure, how the bound behaves in such situations.

In general the approach to add a lazy constraint “by hand” seems a bit odd, since they are automatically added in cases a feasible solution violates them. If you did not so far, you could try to add them at the very beginning with a [Lazy value](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/reference-manual/lazy) of 1, so they are brought into the model with caution.